# Gear VR with Unity and Keystore: thread priority security exception

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oculus, gear-vr

I'm building a Gear VR application created with Unity, but I get the following error when I launch the application:

`"thread priority security exception. make sure the app is signed."`

The application works well when I use Osig Signature in debug, but now I want to build the application as release, so I use Keystore as described in the documentation, but I get the signed error.

Scripting define symbols :

`USE_ENTITLEMENT_CHECK`

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="APP_PACKAGE" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode" android:value="vr_only"/>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>`
```

The submission validator seems valid (I don't think that the warning is important) :

```
***
*** APK/Submission appears to meet all requirements.

***
*** 1 warnings detected. Consider implementing these.
***

 --> GLES version is (not specified) (uses-gl-es)
```

Unity Pro 5.2.1f1

Oculus Utilities for Unity 5 V0.1.0-beta

Answer (score 1):

The first error is covered [here](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?t=22995):

"comment `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from the manifest."

It looks like 'Exclude from Recents' error can also be fixed with something like:

```
<activity android:name=".usb.UsbStorageActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" />
```

Regarding the GLES warning, have you set it in Unity? (`ETC 2 (GLES 3.0)` iirc.)

Comment: I added all the requirements like described here https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-submission-submitting/ but the problem still the same